# AWS Lambda Controller route not matching, with {proxy+} - 404 Not Found

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a .NET core 3.1 project with a GET endpoint. Locally the route works fine - "/api" GET request returns JSON string.

After publishing to my AWS Lambda function, and invoking the lambda via Postman, I get a 404 Not Found response to the "/api" GET request. Full URL: "https://(lambda domain)/default/MyLambda2/api"

In my project's Startup.cs ConfigureServices and Configure methods, I added "LambdaLogger.Log" statements. My log lines show up in CloudWatch (so I am definitely reaching the app). It's just after that, the route fails.

In ConfigureServices method, I have

```
services.AddControllers();
```

In Configure method, I have

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();                
});
```

And in the Controller file

```
namespace LambdaTest.Controllers
{    
    [Route("api")]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
    }
}
```

I have an API Gateway trigger defined for the lambda, with

```
API endpoint: "https://(lambda domain)/default/MyLambda2/{proxy+}"
API type: REST
Authorization: NONE
Method: ANY
```

In Resources tab, I have...

```
/MyLambda2
ANY
 /{proxy+}
ANY
OPTIONS
```

... and I have all Resources deployed to "default" stage (via Actions > Deploy API).

Here is the default auto-generated serverless.template file...

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Transform": "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31",
  "Description": "An AWS Serverless Application that uses the ASP.NET Core framework running in Amazon Lambda.",
  "Parameters": {},
  "Conditions": {},
  "Resources": {
    "AspNetCoreFunction": {
      "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Function",
      "Properties": {
        "Handler": "LambdaTest::LambdaTest.LambdaEntryPoint::FunctionHandlerAsync",
        "Runtime": "dotnetcore3.1",
        "CodeUri": "",
        "MemorySize": 256,
        "Timeout": 30,
        "Role": null,
        "Policies": [
          "AWSLambda_FullAccess"
        ],
        "Events": {
          "ProxyResource": {
            "Type": "Api",
            "Properties": {
              "Path": "/{proxy+}",
              "Method": "ANY"
            }
          },
          "RootResource": {
            "Type": "Api",
            "Properties": {
              "Path": "/",
              "Method": "ANY"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Outputs": {
    "ApiURL": {
      "Description": "API endpoint URL for Prod environment",
      "Value": {
        "Fn::Sub": "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What could be causing the route to not get picked up in lambda?

Thanks

Comment: Are you deploying with a CloudFormation template? The VS templates usually have it as a file called serverless.template. If so could you share that file as well?

Comment: Yes, I am using the default auto-generated serverless.template file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. I needed my route on the controller to be

```
[Route("MyLambda2/api")]
```